# Odd issue with ng-show always evaluating to true

Tags: angularjs

I had a bit of code in my view that would only show up when a particular value was true. Lt looked like this:

```
button type="button" ng-click="attachBarCode('enter')" ng-show="barcodeAllowed.status">Foo</button>
```

This was working until recently. My controller had some logic where, based on Ajax data, it would set $scope.barcodeAllowed.status to true. All of a sudden though, the button was always showing up. To help debug the issue, I added some additional tests to my view:

```
    first test, <span ng-show="!barcodeAllowed.status">DONT SHOW</span><br/>
    second test, <span ng-show="barcodeAllowed.status">DONT SHOW</span><br/>
    test -{{barcodeAllowed.status}}-end -{{!barcodeAllowed.status}}- -{{barcodeAllowed | json}}-<br/>
    test if <span ng-if="barcodeAllowed.status"> if was true</span><p>
```

Here is where things got crazy. *Both* "DONT SHOWS" rendered in my view, even though it seems as if that would be impossible. When I output the values in the third line, I saw false and true, as I expected.

Finally - the ng-if? It worked perfectly! The value did not show up.

I've heard folks mention that ngShow can have scope issues inside a ngif, but my code isn't inside an ngif.

Comment: have you tried something like trying to console.log the scope.barcodeAllowed.status or just {barcodeAllowed.status} in your view just to see what it is set to when this happens? Ive seen something similiar before.

Comment: Yep. In my controller I check it before the if and after. It stays false.

Comment: I would probably try to just write the variable in your view, just to make sure that it is correctly bound, and not targetting a different scope

Comment: Query - if I inspect the DOM I see <span ng-show="..."> in the inspector. The fact that Angular didn't remove that for whatever reason - is that a concern?

Comment: Hmm, the main difference between the show/hide directives and the if-directive is that show/hide will keep it in the DOM, just hiding it, ng-IF will not and will trigger a re-render.

Comment: Oh, and yes, I do write the variable in the view - see the 3rd line? And it prints the right value.

Comment: So to just expand on my last comment, when I do the json version of barcodeAllowed, I see: {"status":false, "ray":1} (ray is just a test value i used). So even though status is false, ng-show still shows stuff.

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr or something similar to reproduce the issue?

Comment: unfortunately not - its part of a larger app. i'll try to recreate it - but i dont know if i can.

Comment: Funny thing worth mentioning. Long time ago since i did angular, but ng-show actually uses a css-class to hide and show your stuff. If that is not handled in the css, it will not work. try to add this in your css : ng-show{display:block}; ng-hide{display:none};

Comment: oh.... wow.. i wonder if that is it. checking.

Comment: just an fyi - thanks for your help - i have to run for a few hours though so willb e slow to update.

Comment: always a pleasure;) 

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Comment: Just try adding the css class ng-hide to your no-show span. If you can't see it then you know your css if working fine.

Comment: I also suggest being more explicit and seeing what happens. Try <span ng-show="barcodeAllowed.status === true">SHOW</span>

Comment: Sometimes if you are setting a true/false value via the return of JSON data from an Ajax call, the values get translated to the string "true" or the string "false".  So saying barcodeAllowed.status when that is a string value will not properly evaluate to TRUE/FALSE.

Answer (score 4):

So, you won't believe what it was. I was using a Content Security policy in my app and on a whim, I disabled it. As soon as I did, it began working. I played around a bit and discovered that I needed to add 'unsafe-eval' to the to the script-src area of my CSP in order for Angular to be able to apply the styles.

Comment: For folks curious, I documented this a bit more here: http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/07/03/using-angular-and-a-content-security-policy-watch-out-for-this

Answer (score 0):

The Ng-show/Ng-hide directives needs a css-class to show/hide, since it just adds a class to your element when the scope-variable is truthy/falsy.

Ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Comment: It adds a class and uses css but you don't have to define the class yourself.  However, it could be that a css rule with more specificity (when !important is used) might override the ng-hide rule when its added.